# What are the differences between a view and a zero-argument procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

In mySQL, I often happen to hesitate between creating a view and creating a stored procedure that doesn't have any argument.

What are the conceptual differences between a view and a zero-argument procedure, besides the fact that a procedure can return several output tables?

Assuming the output we want to obtain consists only of one table, are there performance differences between using a view and using a stored procedure without argument, and are there things that one can do and that the other cannot?

Answer (score 1):

There are many differences. They're used for different things. Here are a few examples off the top of my head, but by no means is this a complete list.

- You can use a view in a SELECT query, applying SQL conditions and projection on its result. You can even join a view to other tables, just like a table.
- You can use a view — if it's an updatable view — as the subject of other SQL statements like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.
- You can't define a view as anything other than a SELECT query. Whereas you can put a variety of different statement types in a procedure.
- You can write blocks of code in a stored procedure to do lots of conditional logic, do both inserts and queries, etc.
- You can use PREPARE and EXECUTE in stored procedures to build dynamic SQL statements at runtime. So you can do things that require runtime parsing, like a pivot-table query.
- You can use DDL in a stored procedure.
- You can start and commit one or multiple transactions in a procedure.
- A procedure is compiled the first time you use it in a session, and every session has to recompile it. Whereas a view is "compiled" once when it's created.
- A procedure can read or set session variables, but a view can't.